# Testing EINTR signal

Tags: c, gdb, signals

In my program, I have a system call 'sendmsg()'. I want to test what will happen if this system call gets interrupted. How should I do it?

```
int test(args) {
          -----
          /* I can use GDB and stop at this point */  
          n = sendmsg(h, send_msg, 0);
          ----
          return n; 
 }

 int test_caller(args) {
           int a, err;
           a = test(arg);
           if (a != what_i_am_expecting) {
               err = error;
               switch (err) {
                   case EINTR:
                       syslog(LOG_ERR, "I WANT TO SEE THIS LOG");
                       break;
                   default:
                }
            } else printf("Everything went well\n");
    return 0;
   }
```

In this same function I have registered a signal handler as follows:

```
1366         struct sigaction sa;
1367         
1368         memset (&sa, '\0', sizeof(sa));
1369         sa.sa_handler = sighdl;
1370         sa.sa_flags = 0; 
1371         (void)sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
```

With this handler:

```
1349 static void
1350 sighdl(int signo)
1351 {
1352         int i = 0;
1353         syslog(LOG_ERR, "got signal %d", signo);
1354         for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
1355         }
1356 }
```

My idea is to break in test() function before calling sendmsg(), then send sigint to pid.
But not sure with this signa;, does it go to EINTR case in test-caller.

Please help!

Comment: **IT IS NOT SAFE TO CALL `syslog` FROM SIGNAL HANDLERS.**  Practically no functions are safe in signal handlers!  Don't do it!

Comment: yes, I am aware of that. Just intended to show that I want to land there.

Comment: while true? what do you mean by that? where shud i add it in above function?

Comment: @Ram: Well that could be causing failures. Use `write(2, "hello\n", 6);` instead.

Comment: ok. Dont worry abt syslog. I want to know how to hit case EINTR:

Comment: Have you considered faking `sendmsg()` by writing (and calling) a function (perhaps called `SendMsg()`) which will call the real function, but also arrange to delay when requested and/or simulate an interrupt (e.g. by using a sub-second sleep to allow you to type the interrupt, or by sending a signal to itself — `kill(getpid(), SIGINT);` — or something similar)?  Would this be close enough to the test you want.  It could also fake the return value and status.  Note that GDB fields interrupts and interprets them as 'wake up, debugger' indications; this complicates testing in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `sendmsg` call is quick. So it hard to signal during it.
But there is a way:

Depending of protocol `sendmsg` will block if the queue of receiver is full.
So, fill the queue some way, and then press CTRL+C when your program is stuck in the `sendmsg` call
(CTRL-C causes SIGINT).

Because you catch SIGINT, program will not exit. The `sendmsg` will return with code -1 and errno EINTR.

Comment: can GDB help anywhere? what If I stop execution between sendmsg and return

Comment: I like this
"you catch SIGINT, program will not exit. The sendmsg will return with code -1 and errno EINTR."
But I am not sure about this statement.

Comment: @Ram : By sending signal after the system call, you can not change return code of the system call. If you use gdb, you may directly modify variables for getting the wanted log. But that is not perfect test.